# Comparing two array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

```
var a = [{
    id: 'Monday',
    slots: [{
        end: "05:00:00 PM",
        start: "08:00:00 AM"
      },
      {
        end: "04:00:00 PM",
        start: "03:00:00 AM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Tuesday',
    slots: [{
      end: "05:00:00 PM",
      start: "08:00:00 AM"
    }]
  }
];
var b = [{
    id: 'Monday',
    slots: [{
        end: "04:00:00 PM",
        start: "06:00:00 AM"
      },
      {
        end: "03:00:00 PM",
        start: "02:00:00 AM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Tuesday',
    slots: [{
      end: "05:00:00 PM",
      start: "08:00:00 AM"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 'Wednesday',
    slots: [{
      end: "05:00:00 PM",
      start: "08:00:00 AM"
    }]
  }
];
```

I tried JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) but as it is nested objects it is not working out. Is there any way to compare both array of nested objects upto start and end?

id(key)s will be same way in both a and b, only timeslots and it's values will change

Comment: "I tried" ... the arrays are not equal?

Comment: "`only timeslots and it's values will change`":  if values are different, then arrays are different. You might want to filter out `slots` and then compare like this `(filteredArray1 == filteredArray2)`

Comment: Given that you already showed the input, what is the expected output and ***why***?

Comment: Expected output is true/false if it is same or different

Comment: Then your current code is correct since the two objects are different. Problem solved.

Comment: Are you also concerned with the matching of object value ? @user521024

Comment: yes, I am concerned with matching object value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can check the value of each and evry nested array's object value .

Below code will console that **both the array's are same**


If you change any value of object , it will result into **Both the array's are not same**

```js
var a = [{
    id: 'Monday',
    slots: [{
        end: "05:00:00 PM",
        start: "08:00:00 AM"
      },
      {
        end: "04:00:00 PM",
        start: "03:00:00 AM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Tuesday',
    slots: [{
      end: "05:00:00 PM",
      start: "08:00:00 AM"
    }]
  }
];

var b = [{
    id: 'Monday',
    slots: [{
        end: "05:00:00 PM",
        start: "08:00:00 AM"
      },
      {
        end: "04:00:00 PM",
        start: "03:00:00 AM"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'Tuesday',
    slots: [{
      end: "05:00:00 PM",
      start: "08:00:00 AM"
    }]
  }
];

var flag = false;
if (a.length != b.length) {
  flag = true;
  console.log("Both array are not same as there don't have equal length");
}
if (flag == false) {
  a.forEach(function(aObject) {
    b.forEach(function(bObject) {
      if (aObject.id == bObject.id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < aObject.slots.length; i++) {
          if ((aObject.slots[i].end != bObject.slots[i].end) || (aObject.slots[i].start != bObject.slots[i].start)) {
            flag = true;
            console.log("Both arrays are not equal");
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}



if(flag == true){
  console.log("both arrays are not same");
}
else{
  console.log("both arrays are same ");
}
```

You can checkout the result of my running code .

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.differenceWith` from lodash, and pass a comparator which compares two arrays, as in:

```
_.differenceWith(a, b, _.isEqual);
```

OR

```
a.sort().every((value, index) => value === b.sort()[index])
```